# Kotlin 1.3.61 fails to resolve return type of extension property on function literal

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, extension-methods

In below example I wrote simple decorator extension that catches exceptions and returns `null` on any error. The problem is that `num1` and `num2` type is inferred as `R?` instead of `Double?`:

```
val <R> (()->R).nothrow: (()->R?) get() = { try { invoke() } catch(ex: Throwable) { null } }

fun main() {
  val num1 = "42"::toDouble.nothrow()
  println(num1)
  val num2 = "english"::toDouble.nothrow()
  println(num2)
}
```

The program output is :

```
42.0
null
```

But when I write

```
num1!! + 3.14
```

I get error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch
```

The candidates are all `plus` operators in existence.

The decompiled java code of `nothrow` extension looks as follows:

```
@NotNull
public static final Function0 getNothrow(@NotNull Function0 $this$nothrow) {
    int $i$f$getNothrow = 0;
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$nothrow, "$this$nothrow");
    return (Function0)(new Function0($this$nothrow) {
       // $FF: synthetic field
       final Function0 $this_nothrow;

       @Nullable
       public final Object invoke() {
          Object var1;
          try {
             var1 = this.$this_nothrow.invoke();
          } catch (Throwable var3) {
             var1 = null;
          }

          return var1;
       }

       public {
          this.$this_nothrow = var1;
       }
    });
 }
```

Why is that?

---

**EDIT**

The problem seems to lie in extension property:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed if you add parentheses around the function you invoke:

```
val num1 = ("42"::toDouble.nothrow)()
println(num1)
val num2 = ("english"::toDouble.nothrow)()
println(num2)
num1!! + 3.14 // Does not fail
```

If you try to write this code in IDEA:

```
"42"::toDouble()
```

It says:

> This syntax is reserved for future use; to call a reference, enclose it in parentheses: (foo::bar)(args)

That's why your code is failing. Your code is just more tricky than just calling a reference, so IDEA can't detect it.

Comment: Hmmm that's interesting. I don't use `::abc()` syntax though, but pass the method reference as receiver for extension function. It should be the same as passing method reference as argument to normal function, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, this problem remains even if we replace method reference with a lambda of similar type. It looks like a bug, because IDEA says that the type of `"42"::toDouble.nothrow()` is `R?`, although we are still in `main` function that does not have any generics. Anyway, calling a property of functional type and calling a function has similar syntax, so it may even be the intended behaviour (calling function over calling functional property, because second can be reached through parentheses), so you should use parentheses (or write `.invoke()` explicitly).

Comment: Well, that's not very uplifting :D I wanted to avoid boilerplate code.

Comment: I don't think that a pair of parentheses (when they are necessary) is boilerplate code

Comment: Well, in simple scenarios it isn't, but I still have nightnamares about consecutive type casts